# Upload HTTP Error error in magento

Tags: magento

When I upload image on server by admin panel,it display error "Upload HTTP Error" in magento.

Answer (score 5):

If you have password protected your root directory of magento using .htaccess file.Remove that restriction and try again.This should work for you.

Comment: You may also allow a specifix IP and use "satisfy any" - so you can stay activ with your HTTP Auth.

Comment: @domi27 This is also good Idea.If we are having a static IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Read this
[Magento Upload HTTP Error](http://www.paprose.com/blog/magento-upload-http-error/)
and This 
[Magento Upload HTTP Error](http://www.shanestillwell.com/index.php/2010/06/03/magento-upload-http-error-solved/)

links are fine, just copy them and past them in your navigator

1: Seems to be down, or to be reconstructed. 
2: http://www.shanestillwell.com/2010/06/03/magento-upload-http-erorr-solved/

Comment: Have you tried your google fuu? https://www.google.com.ec/#q=magento+http+upload+error

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the basic requirement for the Magento.

For example: the server must have mcrypt and GD PHP extensions enabled. If both are enabled. It will automatically remove the HTTP Upload Error.

For getting the extensions, please contact web host and verify if both are enabled.

If you are WHM VPS or Dedicated server owner, refer to Easy Update option on the left menu from the WHM, and from the list enable both and install it. It will take few mins and it will install both extensions on the server.